# Cesium - Bind jquery datepicker to element in entity description

Tags: iframe, datepicker, cesiumjs

I am trying to bind a datepicker to an input field which is displayed in slider-iframe when an entity is clicked in Cesium.js application. But the datepicker is not triggered on click of the textbox. Below is the code I tried:

```
viewer.entities.add({
  id : key,
  description : '<input type="text" class="datepicker1"/>',
  polygon : {
    hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray(coords),
    material : Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
    outline : false
  }
});

$('.cesium-infoBox-iframe').on('focus',".datepicker1", function(){
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker();
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the focus event ever getting triggered?

Comment: @Zac, No.. that's what my query is...

Comment: I would look into using a `Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler` to listen for events, then use `scene.pick` to see what was clicked. Or you may be able to just use the `viewer.selectedEntity`.

Comment: If you have a more specific question or a better example to work off I bet you would get a more complete answer.

Comment: @Zac, here is the js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wkk2013b/